A problem about the existence of primitive function
Let $f(x)$ be a function defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{x}), & x>0\\
\quad 0, &x=0
\end{cases}.
$$
Then, if $f(x)$ has primitive function, what is the value range of $\alpha$?
I calculated some situations: when $\alpha>-1$,$f(x)$ has a primitive function.And when $\alpha=-1$, $f(x)$ has not  primitive function. But how about the left situation? I tried to use improper integrals, but I know integrability and the existence of a primitive function are not equal. So, how to solve the problem when $\alpha<-1$ ?

One thing we can do is to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^\alpha \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\begin{cases}0, & \alpha> 0 \ \nexists, & \alpha\leq 0\end{cases} $$
Then, for $\alpha>0$, $f(x)$ is continuous in every point of its domain and therefore admits primitive.

What's a primitive function?

@SassatelliGiulio antiderivative I think

@SassatelliGiulio Yes,it is antiderivative

How did you decide that $f$ has a primitive for $-1<\alpha \le 0$? Does the primitive actually have $0$ as a right-derivative at $x = 0$?

@Pual Sinclair  Yes.Actually,I had finished this problem.It is a oscillation discontinuity.But you can also find its antiderivative .The key is to prove $g(x)=\cos{\frac{1}{x}},x>0;0,x=0$ has antiderivative.Try to create a new function $h(x)=x^{\alpha+2}\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$,and you can prove it if you write the derivative of $h(x)$.
